# Transaction failure when persisting Kafka messages in batch mode using Quarkus Panache

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a Quarkus application that receives messages from Kafka and persists them in a PostgreSQL database. The application uses the non-reactive flavor of Panache. Upon receiving a message, the message is mapped to a Panache entity which is then merged into the database. This works and looks (simplified) like this:

```
  @Incoming("input-channel")
  @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  @Blocking
  public void consume(Event event) {
    if (event.isInsertOrUpdate()) {
      Entity entity = new Entity()
      /* fill in entity attributes */
      Panache.getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    } else {
      Entity.delete("id", event.getId());
    }
  }
```

As expected, the performance is not great. Using batch processing, I've tried the following approach:

```
  @Incoming("input-channel")
  @Acknowledgment(Strategy.MANUAL)
  @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  @Blocking
  @OnOverflow(value = OnOverflow.Strategy.BUFFER, bufferSize = 2048)
  public CompletionStage<Void> consume(Message<List<Event>> msgs) {
    var batch = msgs.getPayload();
    return Uni.createFrom()
        .item(batch)
        .onItem()
        .transform(function(this::storeEvents))
        .onItem()
        .invoke(msgs::ack)
        .onFailure()
        .invoke(failure -> logger.info("Processing failed with ", failure))
        .subscribeAsCompletionStage();
  }

  private Void storeEvents(List<Event> batch) {
    for (Event event : batch) {
      if (event.isInsertOrUpdate()) {
        Entity entity = new Entity()
        /* fill in entity attributes */
        Panache.getEntityManager().merge(entity);
      } else {
        Entity.delete("id", event.getId());
      }
    }
```

When running this for some time (sometimes hours), the following exception appears:

```
2023-05-27 08:26:13,809 WARN  [com.arj.ats.arjuna] (executor-thread-1) ARJUNA012094: Commit of action id 0:ffffac1ebe13:8d07:6471bc2f:2376 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
2023-05-27 08:26:13,811 WARN  [com.arj.ats.arjuna] (executor-thread-1) ARJUNA012107: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffffac1ebe13:8d07:6471bc2f:2376 commiting with 2 threads active!
2023-05-27 08:26:13,816 WARN  [com.arj.ats.jta] (executor-thread-1) ARJUNA016039: onePhaseCommit on < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=35, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffffac1ebe13:8d07:6471bc2f:2376, node_name=quarkus, branch_uid=0:ffffac1ebe13:8d07:6471bc2f:2379, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=0 > (io.agroal.narayana.LocalXAResource@2d332e1b) failed with exception XAException.XA_RBROLLBACK: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Error trying to transactionCommit local transaction: Enlisted connection used without active transaction
    at io.agroal.narayana.LocalXAResource.xaException(LocalXAResource.java:140)
    at io.agroal.narayana.LocalXAResource.xaException(LocalXAResource.java:134)
    at io.agroal.narayana.LocalXAResource.commit(LocalXAResource.java:72)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelOnePhaseCommit(XAResourceRecord.java:702)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.onePhaseCommit(BasicAction.java:2400)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.End(BasicAction.java:1502)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:96)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1295)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:128)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.NotifyingTransactionManager.commit(NotifyingTransactionManager.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.endTransaction(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:406)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.lambda$handleAsync$2(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:254)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.doInTransaction(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.lambda$handleAsync$3(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:251)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualBiFunction.apply(SlowContextualBiFunction.java:21)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:934)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandleStage(CompletableFuture.java:950)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.handle(CompletableFuture.java:2340)
    at io.smallrye.context.CompletableFutureWrapper.handle(CompletableFutureWrapper.java:192)
    at io.smallrye.context.CompletableFutureWrapper.handle(CompletableFutureWrapper.java:17)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.handleAsync(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:249)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:157)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:107)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:61)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew.java:32)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:38)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:26)
    at org.acme.test.PostgresqlController_Subclass.consume(Unknown Source)
```

This happens using Quarkus 3.0.4.Final with extensions `quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache`, `quarkus-jdbc-postgresql`, `quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka`.

My question: What am I doing wrong? Is batch processing supported in combination with Panache (or Hibernate)?

Comment: not sure if this is the root cause of the issue. Instead of `@Transactional`, we should use `@WithTransaction`. See the [corresponding `quarkus.io` documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache#transactions). I am also not sure whether the `@Blocking` is then still necessary (I assume not).